# Sumar el total y a eso restarle ciertos tipos de comprobantes ademas tiene que estar dividido por mes

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente Query

```
SELECT (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(fechaCAE) - 1, '1900-01-01')) + ' '+
                DATENAME (YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(fechaCAE) - 1900, '1900-01-01'))) As 'fecha'
,SUM(totalComprobante) as 'Monto Facturado'
from FE_COMPROBANTES WHERE CAE is not null 
and CAE <> '{CAE}' and fechaCAE is not null
GROUP BY MONTH(fechaCAE), YEAR(fechaCAE)
ORDER BY  YEAR(fechaCAE), MONTH(fechaCAE)
```

el cual me trae el siguiente valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero Necesito que a este monto se le reste un tipo de comprobante 3 y 8, La columna es tipoComprobante, pero al estar con la función de datename no me esta dejando restar bien en el SUM y que lo siga dividiendo por meses. tendran alguna forma en la que pueda hacerlo estuve ya 2 días tratando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes introducir un `CASE` dentro del `SUM` para discriminar cuando debe sumar

```
SUM(CASE WHEN tipoComprobante in (3,8) then 0 else totalComprobante end) as 'Monto Facturado'
```

La sentencia completa queda así:

```
SELECT (DATENAME (MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(fechaCAE) - 1, '1900-01-01')) + ' '+
                DATENAME (YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(fechaCAE) - 1900, '1900-01-01'))) As 'fecha'
,SUM(CASE WHEN tipoComprobante in (3,8) then 0 else totalComprobante end) as 'Monto Facturado'
from FE_COMPROBANTES WHERE CAE is not null 
and CAE <> '{CAE}' and fechaCAE is not null
GROUP BY MONTH(fechaCAE), YEAR(fechaCAE)
ORDER BY  YEAR(fechaCAE), MONTH(fechaCAE)
```

Solo sumará aquellos comprobantes que no sean tipoComprobante 1 o 8. A todos los efectos es como realizar una resta del total menos esos comprobantes.